# How to configure bash autocomplete for file search and custom search?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I want to have a command autocomplete uploaded scripts that would be run remotely, but the user could also pick a local script to upload. Here is a small example to illustrate the problem I have with the bash complete logic.

```
_test_complete()
{
    local cur prev opts uploaded_scripts
    uploaded_scripts='proc1.sh proc2.sh'
    
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    if [[ ${prev} == '-s' ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${uploaded_scripts}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
}

complete -F _test_complete remote
```

The example almost works but it does not autocomplete local file searches anymore.

```
$ remote -s proc<TAB><TAB>
proc1.sh  proc2.sh

$ remote -s proc1.sh ./<TAB><TAB>
```

Nothing happens when you do the usual file search `./` which should list files in current dir.  Any ideas on how you can enable both ?

---

EDIT: The above example had a problem you could only pick one file with file complete. I hacked a solution which works but if anyone has a better one please leave a comment.  Also with the `-o default` from the accepted answer.

```
_test_complete()
{
    local cur prev opts uploaded_scripts
    uploaded_scripts='proc1.sh proc2.sh'

    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    
    [[ $COMP_CWORD == '1' ]] && LAST_OPT=''
    [[ ${prev:0:1} == '-' ]] && LAST_OPT=${prev}
    
    if [[ ${LAST_OPT} == '-s' ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -o default -W "${uploaded_scripts}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
}

complete -F _test_complete remote
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `complete`'s `-o default` option <sup>(Usually I'd use both `-o default` and `-o bashdefault`)</sup>:

```
complete -o default -F _test_complete remote
```

---

According to `man bash`:

> - *bashdefault*
>
>   Perform the rest of the **default bash completions** if the compspec generates no matches.
> - *default*
>
>   Use **readline's default filename completion** if the compspec generates no matches.

Comment: there is a problem here though. only 1 script will autocomplete with this method  because `${prev}` not -s when its auto completing the 2nd script. `remote -s proc1.sh
`  will not autocomplete further.  How would you get around that ?  somehow back track though COMP_WORDS until you got a -* ?

Comment: i dont quite understand what you mean here. could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: if you try the example `remote -s proc1.sh <TAB><TAB>`  no more completes happen after the 1st one. So i added `[[ ${prev} == '-s' ]] && LAST_OPT=${prev}`  which sets LAST_OPT to `-s`  and i changed the clause to `if [[ ${LAST_OPT} == '-s' ]] ; then `.  This seems to work. Is that what you would do or is there a better way ?

Comment: so what do you want `remote -s proc1.sh <TAB><TAB>` to complete? filenames under current dir? that's what `-o default` is used for here.

Comment: yeh but it only works for 1 file after the -s because it never goes into that if statement again and that is because `${prev}`  is  `"${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"`  and that will be the last file.  if you want to autocomplete 2 files it will fail. thats the bit im trying to figure out now

Comment: with `-o default`, `remote -s proc1.sh <TAB><TAB>` or `remote -s proc1.sh file1 <TAB><TAB>` all works. confusing what you mean by "want to autocomplete 2 files".

Comment: `-o default` does add the ability for you to complete one of these `uploaded_scripts='proc1.sh proc2.sh'` or a file from disk. What I'm saying is if you copy paste that example into a terminal and try `remote -s proc1.sh ` then try tab completing another file from disk or from uploaded_scripts var, then compgen will never be executed because ${prev} is pointing at `proc1.sh` not `-s` anymore.

Comment: yes you have to determine the position (in `COMP_WORDS`) of current arg and its context (before/after) and code the logic accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add all files from the local directory to `COMPREPLY` too. `complete -f -- abc` generates a list of files starting with `abc`.

By the way: Instead of `"${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"` and `COMP_CWORD-1` you can also use `$2` and `$3` which are supplied to any completion function by bash.
But here I completely dropped the `if` since it seems you want to allow multiple files after `-s`. Since you don't suggest `-s` itself, just suggest the files all the time:

```
_test_complete() { 
  local cur="$2" prev="$3" uploaded_scripts='proc1.sh proc2.sh'
  COMPREPLY=( $(
    compgen -W "${uploaded_scripts}" -- "$cur"
    compgen -f -- "$cur"
  ) )
}

complete -F _test_complete remote
```

Note: `COMPREPLY=( $(...) )` is easy to write but has some flaws. Files with spaces in them will be split into multiple suggestions and special symbols like `*` will expand and generate even more suggestions. To avoid this, either set `IFS=$'\n'; set -o noglob` or use `mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <(...)`.
After you have done this, you can use `complete -o filenames -F ...` such that those problematic suggestions are correctly quoted when being inserted too.

Comment: well i wanted for -s to be either local or remote so the -o default will allow that opt to do both completes.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I changed the answer to suggest remote and local files at the same time. From your comments on pynexj's answer, I also decided to remove the `if`.